Laravel 11 Vite change public folder to public_html
I'm trying to change the "public" folder to "public_html" in Laravel 11 Vite.
With Webpack.mix it was a easy task but with Vite I can't seem to make it work.
Isn't this possible in Vite without a symlink or am I missing something?
vite.config.js:
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    build: {
        outDir: 'public_html/build',
    },
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: ['resources/sass/app.scss', 'resources/js/app.js'],
            publicDirectory: 'public_html',
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
});

AppServiceProvider.php:
public function register(): void
{
    # Change public/ to public_html/
    $this->app->bind('path.public', function() {
        return realpath(base_path().'/public_html');
    });
}

Edit:
The error I receive is:
Vite manifest not found at: C:\wamp64\www\demo\public\build/manifest.json

The @vite directive accepts 2 parameters, the first one is the entrypoints array, the second is the build path. You could do something like the following:
@vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'], '../public_html/build')
It is a bit ugly, since under the hood the @vite directive uses the public_path function, which always points to the public directory

Thank you, the second parameter solved this! Weird that I couldn't find this information in the laravel documentation..

I couldn't find it in the docs either, but you can check the code yourself. Check out the following file vendor/laravel/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Vite.php inside of your project (or go here https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/11.x/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Vite.php). You can find out exactly how it works.

if you are running on the local machine with php artisan serve you have to make a custom command to run the server with a your custom path
   {{
        Vite::useBuildDirectory('public_html')
    }}

add this line in your HTML head section
or you can create php -S localhost:8000 -t {{your entry path}}
